# how can i display share images for each article?

Tags: social-sharing

if you take a look at [Technibility](http://www.technobuffalo.com/) you will see share icons for each post. It doesnt seem to be a plugin. But if its custom how is it grabbing the share count?

Comment: http://jetpack.me/support/sharing/

Answer (score 0):

Something similar happens on TNW site, this is the (custom, home build) [plugin they use](https://github.com/thenextweb/TNW-Social-Count)